# Gibbs Sampling / Monte Carlo with Weights

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, gibbs, jags, stan

Consider pairs of data and their population weights $(y_i, \omega_i), i = 1, 2, \dots$ alongside some hierarchical structure, $$y_i\leftarrow\theta_{i(j)} \leftarrow \gamma$$ where $i(j)$ is perhaps the wider group that the $i$th observation belongs to.

Without weights, I might model $$y_i \sim N(\theta_{i(j)}, \sigma^2)$$
$$\theta_i \sim N(\gamma, \sigma_{\theta}^2)$$
so that maybe $\theta$s are group means and $\gamma$ is the population mean, and put some non-informative priors on all the hyper-parameters.
My question is, how I would create a similar model which incorporates the weights? i.e., such that my estimates of the  $\theta$s and $\gamma$ are weighted.

I would be interested in implementing such a model in STAN or JAGS. I think I would be able to do this if I have an understanding of the mathematical background.

Comment: This seems unprincipled and I don't know any better, but I wonder if you can just augment each datapoint by its population weight (so if your population weight is 2, then you'll end up with 2 copies of your datapoint)?

Comment: @mxwsn - certainly something I had considered, and probably my go to solution if I fail to find anything better. Thanks!